# Is it possible to set up a WCF service as REST & SOAP this way?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap

Im trying to combine SOAP and REST under one roof with some modification. But I dont know whether its possbile. My code is below, it used to work when REST only but since I tried to add the extra web service as SOAP (using configuration) it doesnt work. Not sure how to configure it...

I have the interfaces:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IVLSContentServiceREST
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    string EchoWithGet(string s);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke]
    string EchoWithPost(string s);

}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IVLSContentServiceSOAP
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    string EchoWithGet(string s);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke]
    string EchoWithPost(string s);
}
```

Then I have a file called VLSContentService.svc with this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="VLSContentService" CodeBehind="VLSContentService.svc.cs" %>
```

And the cs(codebehind) file:

```
public class VLSContentService : IVLSContentServiceSOAP, IVLSContentServiceREST
{

    string IVLSContentServiceSOAP.EchoWithGet(string s)
    {
        return "You said " + s;
    }

    string IVLSContentServiceSOAP.EchoWithPost(string s)
    {
        return "You said " + s;
    }


    string IVLSContentServiceREST.EchoWithGet(string s)
    {
        return "You said " + s;
    }

    string IVLSContentServiceREST.EchoWithPost(string s)
    {
        return "You said " + s;
    }

}
```

And the configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <!---Add the service-->
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="VLSContentServiceBehaviour" name="VLSContentService">
        <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="VLSContentServiceEndpointBehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IVLSContentServiceREST"/>
        <endpoint address="soap" behaviorConfiguration="VLSContentServiceEndpointBehaviour" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IVLSContentServiceSOAP"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <!---Add the behaviours-->
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="VLSContentServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>


      <!---Add the behaviours-->
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="VLSContentServiceEndpointBehaviour">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes it's possible and I did it that way. I'll post my solution later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need two versions of the contract - just host the same contract at two endpoints using different bindings

```
 <services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="VLSContentServiceBehaviour" name="VLSContentService">
    <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="VLSContentServiceEndpointBehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IVLSContentService"/>
    <endpoint address="soap" behaviorConfiguration="VLSContentServiceEndpointBehaviour" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IVLSContentService"/>
  </service>
</services>
```